# Responsive menu push the content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using media queries to make my website responsive.It all looks awesome , but when I open the mobile menu , it pushes all the content below.
[image]

So my question is , how can I adjust the mobile menu not to push the content down? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute/Fixed position on your #main-Menu

```
#main-Menu{
    position: 'absolute',
    background-color: '#c41a17',
    z-index: 99999,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

sorry @kamikazeOvrld, but it seems there are errors in your answer? Unless I am mistaken, it should be:

```
#main-Menu{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #c41a17;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

I removed the ' and , characters and swapped the trailing , after the 99999 for a ;

I am still learning, so feel free to tell me I am wrong.
Gav